# Perfomance measurment for reverse string and appending suffix

Tags: java, string, algorithm

I am reading about string reverse:

First code:

```
public static String reverse(String s) {
  String rev = "";
  for (int i = s.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
     rev += s.charAt(i);
  return rev;
}
```

Second code:

```
public static String reverse(String s) {
   StringBuilder rev = new StringBuilder();
   for (int i = s.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
      rev.append(s.charAt(i));
   return rev.toString();
}
```

It's mentioned that using string we have quadratic time and using string builder we have linear time.

And on page 9 about arrry of suffixes using string is better here.

I am not getting how author concluded this in above both cases.

Can any one please help me here?

Answer (score 0):

In the first code:

```
public static String reverse(String s) {
   String rev = "";
   for(int i = s.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
      rev += s.charAt(i);
   return rev;
}
```

Each time you do `rev += s.charAt(i);`, a `StringBuilder` is created, then the content of `rev` is appended, then `s.charAt(i)` is appended, and then `StringBuilder` is converted into a *String*. That would be `s.length() - 1` `StringBuilder`s and the same amount of Strings.

In the second version:

```
public static String reverse(String s) {
   StringBuilder rev = new StringBuilder();
   for(int i = s.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
      rev.append(s.charAt(i));
   return rev.toString();
}
```

There will be only a single `StringBuilder` and a single String.

Regarding your second confusion, can you please elaborate more on this? It's hard to tell what the author meant.

Answer (score 0):

Class "java.lang.StringBuffer" contains method "reverse", you can use it instead of self-written code.